# Field-Group Tabs not displaying on product page

Tags: 8, commerce, entities

I'm trying to display a handful of fields as tabs on my product detail pages, but it seems that the field-group tabs are being completely ignored by the Commerce product display. Anyone else have this problem? Did I miss something in the tab setup/display?

The fields display as any other field for the Product, just output as regularly expected. As mentioned, just seems to ignore the 'tabs' display.

[image: Screen shot of field setup]

Answer (score 0):

Kind of late to the party, but I ran into this same problem earlier today and it appears to be caused by the fact that the Field Group module hardcodes the entity types that it latches onto.

The 1.x-dev version now includes a `HOOK_field_group_content_element_keys_alter()` that you can use to expose any entity type to the Field Group module.

To expose products and product variations you need to create a custom module and hook into the above alter function like this

```
MYMODULE_field_group_content_element_keys_alter(&$keys) {

  if (!isset($keys['commerce_product_variation'])) {
    $keys['commerce_product_variation'] = 'product_variation';
  }

  if (!isset($keys['commerce_product'])) {
    $keys['commerce_product'] = 'product';
  }

}
```

Hopefully this will be integrated into Drupal Commerce in the near future, but for now this is the only way.

*Edit* You can read up on the actual issue here https://www.drupal.org/node/2842280